# Avahi & cups on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, cups, avahi

I set up cups and avahi on FreeBSD 8.0. However cups printer does not shows in `avahi-browse -a` on client (other things like ssh server are shown). Additionally if I try to run `avahi-browse -a` on server it does not succeed:

```
# avahi-browse -a
Failed to create client object: Daemon not running
```

CUPS is built with avahi support. Dbus is running. Cups have sharing enabled in web interface.

Comment: What exactly are the lines in cupsd.conf which configure `BrowseRemoteProtocols` and `BrowseLocalProtocols`? What are the other `Browse*...`-Settings? (I.o.w.: `grep Browse /etc/cups/cupsd.conf` results). There should appear a dnssd in the results... Next, set `LogLevel debug2` (and revert back after you're finished testing), restart cupsd, and then `grep -iE '(dnssd|dns_sd)' /var/log/cups/error_log`.

Comment: Here's a (still unresolved) bug regarding avahi support in CUPS' tracker: http://www.cups.org/str.php?L3066 -- and here's one in Ubuntu's tracker: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/465916 (Both of these have suggested patches).

Answer (score 1):

For second problem, add avahi daemon to autostart and run it:

```
PH34R# echo "avahi_daemon_enable=YES" >> /etc/rc.conf
PH34R# /usr/local/etc/rc.d/avahi-daemon start
Starting avahi-daemon.
PH34R# avahi-browse -a
+   bge0 IPv4 PH34R                      _workstation._tcp    local
....snip....
```

Comment: The avahi daemon is enabled & is running (verified by `pgrep` & appearance on Linux)

Comment: Is there a firewall on server?

Comment: Ups. Sorry - I haven't got message. Yes but it was tested without.

Comment: Hmm. `avahi-browse -a` started working after upgrade to 8.1